# How would i clear an EmailJS form after the user hits submit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, email, preventdefault

Currently if the user hits send, the only way to know if it worked is the button click animation, and would only know for sure if they inspected the page and saw the 'OK' message in console.

I'd like to at least clear all input fields to let them know it worked. Below is the entire Email.js component just in case.

I hope this is enough information to help me out, EmailJS has been very helpful and works wonderfully but its not something my peers and I have experience with so I'm a bit stuck.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Email.css';

const Email = () => {
    const form = useRef();

    const sendEmail = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        emailjs.sendForm(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVICE_ID, process.env.REACT_APP_TEMPLATE_ID, form.current, process.env.REACT_APP_USER_ID)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
        });
    };
    
    return (
        <div className="Email">
            <div className="nav">
                <Link to="/" className="Home">Home</Link>
            </div>
            <h1>Email Me!</h1>
            <form ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail}>
                <div>
                <label>Name:</label>
                <input className="info-box" type="text" name="user_name" />
                </div>
                <div>
                <label>Email:</label>
                <input className="info-box" type="email" name="user_email" />
                </div>
                <div>
                <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" className="Message"/>
                </div>
                <div classname="Button-container">
                <input className="Button" type="submit" value="Send" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <Link to="/resume" className="Back">Back</Link>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Email
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put a ref on each, and then do:

```
theRef.current.value = "";
```

For each, or bind a state to each input seen in the beta docs of React:
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/managing-state#reacting-to-input-with-state

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late with this answer but hopefully this helps others.
Since you are using Email.js you can utilize reset after the .then((result))

Here's an example of what it should look like:

```
.then(
    (result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
      // Clears form/inputs after button is Selected
      form.current.reset();
    }
```

Hope this helps.